# How to automatically update documents generated by another system as new versions?

Tags: 2013, document-library, file-upload, versioning, api

We want to share documents in a SharePoint Document Library (SP 2013) which are automatically generated each week by another software system.

These documents are in PDF and RTF format (maybe also html).

I would like to upload the documents once first "by hand" and then let the other software system overwrite the documents and check-in a new version.

How can this be done programmatically (the easiest possible way)?

Comment: IMO you could stick with the OS built-in Task Scheduler to do the file saving (copying?) to the library's path. Whether this is done using batches, VBS, VBA or something else is up to the source platform & your personal favor. Does this sound sufficient for your requirement?

Comment: sounds good - where can I find examples how to do that? IMHO it is not sufficient to copy the files to the correct library, but also to publish them as a new x.0 version which is visible to the users.

Comment: 1. Create a batch to copy files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder) Note: requires sufficient user permissions in both source and destination & 2. Create a basic batch file task on Task Scheduler (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler) Note: you need to set a weekly trigger & force replace existing file if it's using the same name. Do you really need to use a publishing process/minor versions? What's the end user purpose? That might require some further setup.

Comment: Thanks for your explications! I want to keep old version to document the changes of the documents. We won't need minor versions in this case, but they are enabled in general in the document library.

Comment: To have a version history you won't need a publishing process/minor versions - only `Create major versions` setting is required. The document's would automatically have versions as `1.0`, `2.0` and so on. This means the files would be in a published state once they are copied to the destination.

Comment: I know, but for other files (which are in the same library) I excplicitely also want to use minor versions, so I cannot disable the feature for the whole library

Comment: As the auto-publishing requires customization you'd have to either a) stick with major versions, b) do the publishing manually, c) use one library for one purpose (generally recommended) or d) choose an alternative manner of an approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would either built a small console app using CSOM or use PowerShell and CSOM together.

I haven't checked if this code works, but it probably look something like this:

```
using (var context = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(uri.ToString(), token))
            {
                var web = context.Web;
                using (var fs = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sourceFilePath);

                    FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();

                    flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs;
                    flciNewFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
                    flciNewFile.Overwrite = overWriteIfExists;

                    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

                    context.Load(uploadFile);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    fs.Close();

                    //publish the file
                    uploadFile.Publish("comment");
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```